# RegEx for parsing repeated groups

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

The source string contain tags like this:

```
>>>tagA
contents 1
<<<tagA
...
>>>tagB
contents 2
<<<tagB
...
```

I need to extract tag names and contents inside them. This is what I've got but still not working:

```
(?<=(>>>(?<tagName>.+)$))(?<contents2>.*?)(?=(<<<.+)$)
```

It [results](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%28%3E%3E%3E%28%3F%3CtagName%3E.%2B%29%24%29%29%28%3F%3Ccontents%3E.*%3F%29%28%3F%3D%28%3C%3C%3C.%2B%29%24%29&i=%3E%3E%3EtagA%0D%0Acontents%201%0D%0A%3C%3C%3CtagA%0D%0A...%0D%0A%3E%3E%3EtagB%0D%0Acontents%202%0D%0A%3C%3C%3CtagB%0D%0A...&o=sm) to two matches but the tagName in the second match captured multiple lines:

```
tagA 
contents 1 
<<<tagA
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why the look-behind/look-ahead zero-length assertions, if you are (seemingly) only caring about the captured named groups anyway? Am i perhaps missing something about your use case? Why not "simply" `>>>(?<tagName>[^\n\r]+)[\n\r]+(?<contents>.*?)<<<` (requires single-line matching option) ;-)

Comment: One thing I understood: RegEx is a real pain until you fully learn it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
>>>(?<tagName>.+?)[\r\n]+(?s:(?<contents>.*?))<<<
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3E%3E%3E%28%3F%3CtagName%3E.%2B%3F%29%5B%5Cr%5Cn%5D%2B%28%3Fs%3A%28%3F%3Ccontents%3E.*%3F%29%29%3C%3C%3C&i=%3E%3E%3EtagA%0D%0Acontents%201%0D%0A%3C%3C%3CtagA%0D%0A...%0D%0A%3E%3E%3EtagB%0D%0Acontents%202%0D%0A%3C%3C%3CtagB%0D%0A...)

**Details**

- `>>>` - a `>>>` substring
- `(?<tagName>.+?)` - Group "tagName": any 1+ chars as few as possible
- `[\r\n]+` - one or more CR or LF symbols
- `(?s:(?<contents>.*?))` - Group "contents": an inline modifier group matching any 0+ chars, but as few as possible
- `<<<` - a `<<<`  substring.

In C#:

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @">>>(?<tagName>.+?)[\r\n]+(?s:(?<contents>.*?))<<<");
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/jGGdMg):

```
var s = ">>>tagA\ncontents 1\n<<<tagA\n...\n>>>tagB\ncontents 2\n<<<tagB\n...";
var matches = Regex.Matches(s, @">>>(?<tagName>.+?)[\r\n]+(?s:(?<contents>.*?))<<<");
foreach (Match m in matches) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["tagName"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["contents"].Value);
}
```

Output:

```
tagA
contents 1

tagB
contents 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, we would likely start with a simple expression which is bounded with `>>>` and `<<<`, maybe something similar to:

```
>>>(.+)\s*(.+)\s*<<<.+
```

which we are having our desired data in these two capturing groups:

```
(.+)
```

and we would script the rest of our problem.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iPb5st/1/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @">>>(.+)\s*(.+)\s*<<<.+";
        string input = @">>>tagA
            contents 1
            <<<tagA

            >>>tagB
            contents 2
            <<<tagB

            >>>tagC

            contents 2

<<<tagC
";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]